# What spells can familiars use?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, touch-attacks

I have a question regarding familiars gained through *Find Familiar* for non-Warlocks.

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch,
>   your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the
>   spell.

I've read a number of places where people suggest that there are a number of touch attack spells that can be used, but I can find only three: *Shocking Grasp*, *Inflict Wounds*, and *Forbiddance*.

Are there other spells that are allowed?

Can spells with a range of *Self* be cast via a familiar?

Comment: You are asking if a familiar can cast a self-touch spell on itself or are you trying to cast a spell through your familiar onto yourself for some reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Spells with a range of self cannot be cast via familiar

The restriction you quote acts exactly as it says: you can *only* cast *touch*-ranged spells through your familiar. "Self" != "touch," so you're out of luck.

---

As for touch spells that damage someone, you correctly got *forbiddance*, *inflict wounds*, and *shocking grasp*, but you missed *symbol* and *glyph of warding*. But they're strange edge-cases—the damage isn't done when the spell's cast, but rather when the glyph is triggered. There's also *plane shift* which, when cast on an unwilling target, is a spell attack which doesn't do any damage.

*Magic stone*—from the [Elemental Evil Player's Companion](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/EE_PlayersCompanion.pdf)—is another edge-case: you cast the spell on the stones via touch, but then make a ranged spell attack with them to damage someone.

Answer (score 4):

- light
- magic stone
- mending
- shillelagh
- shocking grasp
- spare the dying
- ceremony
- cure wounds
- goodberry
- identify
- illusory script
- inflict wounds
- jump
- longstrider
- mage armor
- snare
- arcane lock
- continual flame
- darkvision
- gentle repose
- lesser restoration
- nystul's magic aura
- protection from poison
- rope trick
- warding bond
- feign death
- glyph of warding
- meld into stone
- nondetection
- remove curse
- revivify
- tiny servant
- tongues
- death ward
- freedom of movement
- leomund's secret chest
- stone shape
- awaken
- contagion
- greater restoration
- hallow
- raise dead
- reincarnate
- create homunculus
- druid grove
- forbiddance
- guards and wards
- true seeing
- plane shift
- regenerate
- resurrection
- sequester
- simulacrum
- clone
- mind blank
- foresight
- power word heal
- true resurrection

Comment: Quite a list! Where did you gather of this information? Or did you look through each of the books yourself and compile it on a spell by spell basis?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. The site's answers are *evergreen*, so, as the game expands, this list will become more and more obsolete. That typically makes answering a question with an explanation that's followed by examples more useful in the long run than what purports to be a complete list. Please consider including such an explanation. Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: @Adam: I don't know about Mirmalis, but you can filter the lists on [DNDMagic.com](http://www.dndmagic.com/?search=true&class=all&school=all&range=touch) and [Roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells%20List#content) by the range of "Touch". It doesn't look like you can filter by range on DNDBeyond, but [you can sort by range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?page=6&sort=range) and then find where the Touch spells begin.

Answer (score 1):

quick list of "touch" spells (from my feylock spell list):

Guidance, Spare the dying, Illusory script, Protection from Evil and Good, Invisibility, Spider Climb, Fly, Gaseous Form, Remove Curse, Tongues, Greater Invisibility, True Seeing, Plane Shift, Foresight.

Ritual Spells: Identify, illusory Script, Beast Sense, Gentle Repose, Feign Death, Meld Into Stone, Drawmij’s Instant Summons, Forbiddance

Eldritch invocation: Armor of Shadows

There are definitly others in the PHB (cure wounds for example)